# Enable SSLv2 in Apache

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf, rhel6, sslv2

There's a ton of information out there regarding disabling SSLv2, but I can't find anything on enabling it in Apache2's ssl.conf page. Despite the security concerns, I would like to enable SSLv2 alongside TLS and SSLv3. I have tried the following configuration and am still unable to verify that SSLv2 is available. Might I need to add certain SSL Cipher Suites for SSLv2 to work? 
(by the way I am using Red Hat Enterprise)

[This is a snippet from /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YtbB.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible on any normal build of OpenSSL -- SSLv2 is usually blocked at compilation time.  You'd need a custom OpenSSL build, then your httpd config would work.

Comment: thanks for the info! A million configurations later, it's nice to have some closure.